# C# - Factorial and power in one function

Tags: c#

I have this simple code that based on a dropdown list. If *Factorial* is selected then type a number and submit and for power it is the same.

I have:

```
    double x;
    double y;
    double result;
    double m;
    int answer = 1;

    private void factorial(int num)
    {
        for(int x = 1; x <= num; x++)
        {
            answer = answer * x;
        }
    }


    private void pow(double x, double y)
    {
        m = Math.Pow(x, y);
        result = m;
    }
```

And the design:

```
        if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            int fact;
            fact = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            factorial(fact);
            textBox2.Text = answer.ToString();
        }

        if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            x = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            y = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            pow(x, y);
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
```

So, how can I make pow() and factorial() into one function and do the same thing?

Comment: OK. What is your question?

Comment: How to make pow() and factorial() in to one function(method) @S.Akbari

Comment: why would you want power and factorial to be one function? they do 2 different things

Comment: trying to do something different @Century just trying so if someone can help

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to change 'void factorial' to 'int factorial' and to change 'void pow' to 'double pow' and use return value instead of saving results into instance fields?

Comment: It is bad practice to use member variables (in this case `result` and `answer`) this way. You shouldn't unnecessarily couple member variables to functions being executed in a specific way. The design proposed by @rudolf_franek is easier to follow.

Comment: It is simple enough to create a function to do both -- just make a new function that does both what `factorial()` and `pow()` do. It can even simply call them. But this whole thing is a poor design. If you want to do 2 things, then call 2 functions. And the functions should not be putting their results in member variables -- they should return their results to the caller, and the caller should decide what to do with them.

Comment: @Joseph they take different amount and type of arguments, return 2 different types and do something different, so I don't see why someone would want to merge this 2 functions in one. Plus what the others said, don't use member variables but return values, it's just bad practice

Comment: thanks to all for this useful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit messy, but it should do the job:

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        int fact;
        fact = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        factorialPow(fact, 0, 0, 0);
        textBox2.Text = answer.ToString();
    }

    if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        x = double.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        y = double.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        factorialPow(0, x, y, 1);
        textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
    }
```

And:

```
private void factorialPow(int num, double x, double y, int selectedIndex)
        {
            switch (selectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
                    {
                        answer = answer * i;
                    }
                    break;

                case 1:
                    m = Math.Pow(x, y);
                    result = m;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Disclaimer: I in no way condone this kind of coding, there are many, many ways to do this in a much cleaner, more efficient approach, but like I said it'll do the job.

**Edit:**

I also believe that what you posted was absolutely fine, you could add this extra method as a step between your functions, as so:

```
private void factorialOrPow(int num, double x, double y, int selectedIndex)
        {
            switch (selectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    factorial(num);
                    break;

                case 1:
                    pow(x, y);
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you felt the disclaimer was necessary, why not provide a better answer?  Offering clunky solutions to clunky problems only perpetuates bad behavior.  You are missing a teaching opportunity.

Comment: thank you! but in this line `factorialPow(0, x, y);` give an error **there is no argument**

Comment: Sorry about that @Joseph, I had forgotten to enter that, it's fixed now.

Comment: start at i = 2 ?

Comment: you dont need to *1 do you?

Comment: fixed by adding 0 `factorialPow(0, x, y, **0**);`

Comment: @Jospeh, I would advise using `factorialPow(0, x, y, 1);` as the last parameter is for directing the other parameters to the correct method, which also applies to the method in my **Edit**.